# how to control interface index in Centos?

Tags: centos

For one of our network interface we are getting the interface index( scope id) as 258. Due to this we are having issues. Generally it comes as 17 but some times coming as 3 digits. Is there any way to control this? How these ids are generated? Here bond2.4089 interface is a VLAN on bond configuration. This is on Centos 6.7.

```
258: bond2.4089@bond2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 9c:b6:54:98:70:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.149/24 brd 172.16.0.255 scope global bond2.4089
    inet6 fe80::9eb6:54ff:fe98:70c2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Who cares? Anywhere that it's actually important, you should be using the name (`bond2.4089`) anyway.

Comment: we have some issues using name directly because of "."